# How do I color selective residues on the surface of a protein in pymol?

Tags: pymol

I am somewhat familiar with the pymol userface, but not very good with commands. I'm working with a pentameric subunit protein and I want to color specific residues on the surface of the protein, not just the cartoon. I can use select resi #-#, and color those with the (sele) tab on the right, but I do not know how to color the surface this way. When you select the sequence it will only color the cartoon. Any suggestions?

I'm using PyMOL 2.3.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you are seeing reds and blues on the surface? If so, these are the sidechain oxygens and nitrogens. So you need to colour the whole residue not only the `element C` atoms. `color 0xFF7F50, resi 123` will colour the residue in the cartoon and surface as I omitted and `element C`. To revert `color atomic`.

In PyMOL an atom has a colour, which is then used by the representations. To have a differentially coloured representation, you need to make a copy of the object. `create copied, obj_name` and `hide cartoon` and `show surface` will do it.